# Android Memory Crashes

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I am playing with Cocos2d nowadays and facing lot many memory related issues.

Anybody can tell me any best way to manage the memory or find memory crashes. I have tries MAT plugin(http://www.eclipse.org/mat/).

Any other tool or way ?

Help required. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, garbage collection occurs because of tons of small, short-lived objects. Try to reuse views if possible.  I recommend that you go through this [presentation by Dubroy](http://dubroy.com/blog/google-io-memory-management-for-android-apps/). You will know how to use the tools effectively

The only other option I can think of is:

- [Valgrind](http://blog.mozilla.com/jseward/2011/09/27/valgrind-on-android-current-status/) port for Android